# Placing dataframes into excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

i have two dataframes; df and df2. I need to place them into an excel, with df being in one sheet and df2 being in another sheet. What would be the easiest way to do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```